# gorm.io/gorm why should cap 0 set 20

Tags: go-gorm

code in gorm/scan.go
there is a section where cap 0 is assigned a value of 20

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vjCd.png)
what is the meaning of this code.

through this func.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTHbp.png)

i hope to get true,not false.
Is there a better way to judge but not by len()